# Ограничить права доступа к директории в apache

Tags: безопасность, хостинг

Залил сайт на хостинг. Нужно сделать чтоб пользователь не мог пройти по ссылки например www.site.com/images/

Answer (score 2):

Создайте в директории .../images/ файл index.html. Можно даже и пустой, но лучше, чтобы там выдавалась фраза "Error 403: Access forbidden." И усё!

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в директории `/images/` файл с именем `.htaccess` (именно так, с точкой) и запишите в него строку

```
Options -Indexes
```

или еще лучше

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Если файл `.htaccess` уже существует, то тогда просто допишите в файл одну из строк, указанных выше.

Answer (score 0):

А как Ваш пользователь тогда получит картинки, размещенные на страницах (если точно следовать примеру)?
Я так понимаю, Вас интересует запрет на запись в данную директорию.
Если дело происходит в Fedora, то могу дать такой нетривиальный рецепт: [SELinux & Apache](http://forum.russianfedora.ru/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=5292)
Если в Debian - использовать права доступа на папки: этого вполне достаточно.
Однако, не забудьте, права на чтение должны быть обязательно у Апача на папки Вашего сайта.